# Exceptionhandler for Enum in request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, enums, controller-advice

I have a Get request: `\allTopic`
It inputs a `filterCriteria` custom object which contains multiple fields and one of those is an Enum called `Role`, which is either student or teacher

And there are many more different API calls with different Enums. So I want to create @controllerAdvice that can handle all these.

I need help with

1. Annotations to put in the Get API controller function header
2. Annotations to put in the filterCriteria class
3. What particular exception to handle in @exceptionHandler in @controlleradvice

Answer (score 0):

I have some similar code as per your need, please have a look

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = PageNotFoundException.class)
    public String pageNotFoundException(PageNotFoundException exception){
        return "error/404";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = AuthFailedException.class)
    public String authFailedException(AuthFailedException exception){
        return "error/401";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = ServerException.class)
    public String serverException(ServerException exception){
        return "error/500";
    }
}

Afterwards, you can throw any of the given type of exception.
please note, you have to create such your exception.

Example:
```

public class PageNotFoundException  extends RuntimeException{

}

```
I hope, it helps!
```